# Exam question: Show that each infinite L-structure has a countable, elementary substructure

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I've had the following question in a midterm exam about first order logic, and didn't manage to solve it:

> Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a language and $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ structures over $\mathcal{L}$. We say "$\mathcal{A}$ is an **elementary substructure** of $\mathcal{B}$" (short $\mathcal{A}\preccurlyeq \mathcal{B}$), if $\mathcal{A}$ is a substructure of $\mathcal{B}$ and if for all formulas $\phi$ over $\mathcal{L}$ the following holds true:
>
> $\quad \quad\quad\mathcal{A} \models \phi \Leftrightarrow \mathcal{B}\models \phi$
>
> **Now prove**:
> Let $\mathcal{L}$ be countable. Every infinite $\mathcal{L}$ structure has a countable, elementary substructure.
> **Note**: Construct a countable Set $B_0 \subseteq B$, that for each formula $\phi(x,y)$ over $\mathcal{L}$ and for each tuple $a\in B_0$ contains a $b$ with $\mathcal{B} \models \phi(a,b)$, if such a $b$ exists.

I honestly wasn't able to solve this with the time given, and it seems to be way to long a proof for an exam. I nevertheless want to understand this, since we didn't get any solutions afterwards.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(for every formula/funciton $P$, I denote $n_P$ as the number of variable it takes, and if $G$ is a function, $G[\cdot]$ is the image)

Let ${\cal A}$ be infinite model of some countable theory.

Let $B_0\subseteq A$ be countable, let $F$ be the set of function symbols, now for each $φ$ formula define $f_φ$ such that:

If $\bar x\in A^{n_φ-1}$ such that $∃y(φ(y,\bar x))$ we have $φ(f_φ(\bar x), \bar x)$, otherwise $f_φ(\bar x)$ is some arbitrary element of $A$(we need AC to prove such $f$ exists.)

Then let $B_{k+1}=B_k\cup\bigcup_\limits{f\in F}f[B_k^{n_f}]∪\bigcup_\limits{φ\text{ formula}}f_φ[B_k^{n_φ}]$ and $B=\bigcup B_k$(this is the closure of all of the function symbols and the functions we defined), because the theory is countable, and there are only countable formulas, $B$ is countable.

Now use Tarski–Vaught test to show that $B$ with the same interpretation as $\cal A$ is elementary substructure

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. The only problem I have with understanding it is that we never covered the Tarski-Vaught test, so I am unsure if this is the way I was supposed to solve it in the exam.

Comment: @nshct did you cover "canonical model of a theory"?

Comment: Sadly, no. This was a midterm last week, and my course is an introduction to logic one. We only covered formula syntax, the hilbert system and gödels completeness theorem. That's why I am so confused. They even defined "elementary" in the exam, as you can see. Don't know how I was supposed to solve this with the basic stuff we got.

Comment: @nshct in what method did you prove the completeness theorem?

Comment: We sadly didn't. We only showed in that chapter that a theory has a model iff it is not contradictory (using henkins theories), and then showed the compactness theorem. It's weird to me, the stated goal of the chapter was to prove it, but it apparently wasn't finished.

Comment: I'm going to give you the tick anyways, its a very good answer in general :)

Comment: Okay, "a theory has a model iff it is not contradictory", so given a theory T with not contradictions you created a model using Henkin's functions right? If you take a look on this model, you can show that the model you get is the size of the language, if M is an infinite model of a countable theory T, create T' to be the set of all formulas true in M, add to the language countably many constant symbols, create a new theory T'' to be T'+for every 2 constant symbols a,b the axiom "a≠b", now Henkin model you create for this will be the countable model you wanted

Comment: Oh I think I get it know! Thank you!